# Is my `operator.` (operator dot) specification backward compatible and unambiguous?

Tags: c++, operator-overloading, language-lawyer, operator-keyword, c++20

There is some debate about whether and how `operator.` should be introduced to the standard for [c++20](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b20), as far as I know none have been accepted. I thought of what seemed to be an intuitive implementation of the idea

Here is my attempt at specifying the use of `operator.`

invokations of `operator.` will use first attempt to access a member of the calling object (like the default behavior). If that fails 
it will then call the user defined `operator.`

in order to force a minimum depth, the user may invoke a repeated `.`

example:

```
class A {
    int a;
}

class B {
    double a;
    A b;
    A& operator.() { return b; }
}

class C {
    char a;
    B c;
    B& operator.() { return c; }
}

int main() {
    C foo;

    foo.a    // char
    foo..a   // double
    foo...a  // int
    foo....a // <error>
    foo.b    // A
    foo..b   // A (equivalent to previous)
    foo...b  // <error>
    foo.c    // B
    foo..c   // <error>
}
```

Explicit invokation of `operator.` (`<class>.operator.().<member>`) will be treated equivalently to simpley typing `.` (`<class>.<member>`)

```
foo.operator.().a is the equivelent to foo.a
foo.operator.().operator.().a is equivalent to foo..a
```

The return value of operator.() need not be a member. For example, it may return a reference to a global object. Additionally, 
it may have more code than a simple return statement;

```
C global_C;

class D {
    C& operator.() { global_C.a = 'a'; return global_C; }
}
```

`operator.` may be used as a unary operator as well, acting much like a cast/getter. The following main would be valid:

```
int main() {
    C foo;
    B bar;

    bar = foo.;
}
```

It follows that `(<object>.).<member>` is equivalent to `<object>..<member>`

To force different behavior between unary operation and binary/forwarded operaton, define the unary definition with a dummy variable passed to it.

```
class E {
    C& operator.();//forwarded
    C& operator.(int dummy);//unary
}
```

If you wish to disallow unary operation, you may set it equal to `delete`

```
class F {
    C& operator.();//forwarded
    C& operator.(int) = delete;//F has no unary
}
```

of course, the usual const and non const versions are allowed;

```
class G {
    C g;
    const C& operator.() const;
    C& operator.();
}
```

Does this implementation of `operator.` allow in all cases someone to add an `operator.` to an existing class
without breaking old code that uses it? Are there any cases where `operator.` is ambiguous? Also, a slightly more
opinionated question, does this implementation lead to any highly non-intuitive results?

Comment: RIP compiler. No, really, why do you want this? This is probably too broad for SO.

Comment: I am definitely not alone in wanting this. Even Bjarne Stroustrup wants this. It would make wrapper functions much easier

Comment: @Yakk are `..` and `...` already existing constructs?

Comment: I cannot believe that `...` won't break everything; `...` is used for template pack expansion (and old school varargs).  Imagine `(some stuff)...` -- is that a pack expansion or a call to 3 dots?   Will that depend on the type of `some stuff`?  What if `some stuff`'s type is depenent on the current template arguments?

Comment: @Yakk Oh, that's right. I'll look into how that could fit in (or not)

Comment: @Yakk-AdamNevraumont I bet it could be worked around, similar to how `SomeType x(Args...);` will unambiguously mean to initialize `x`, at the cost of adding even more complexity to the language.

Comment: Making wrapper functions easier doesn't sound like much of a compelling reason. At least not with the semantics you suggested.

Comment: There is a bunch of magic in both `foo.operator.().x` and `foo.x` that isn't in `auto&& y = foo.operator.(); y.x;`.  So that is strange.  Personally I'd get rid of `foo.operator.().x` being the same as `foo.x`; make `foo.operator.()` the zero-magic version.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's not a question about the language as it is today, it's a question about how the language could be tomorrow. This question belongs on [std-proposals](https://groups.google.com/a/isocpp.org/forum/#!forum/std-proposals)

Comment: Also this depth idea with repeated calls seems fundamentally at odds with the whole point of doing `operator.()`...

Comment: ideally repeated calls would be only for edge cases. most of the time you could just use `.` my motivation for doing it this way is to be able to add it to existing classes without breaking code

Comment: I would think it would be more useful to allow code to define a family of operators of forms like `.identifier`, or `.identifer.identifier`, `or `.identifier[int index1]`, etc.

Comment: @supercat I don't really understand what you are suggesting. Could you provide a simple example perhaps?

Comment: @rtpax: Sure.  Suppose one wants to have a class member that can be read using the same syntax as an array of structures (e.g. `myThing.coords[index].x`, but may use a different storage format internally.  While it would be possible to have `coords` yield an object that contains a pointer to `myThing`, with a `[]` overload that builds and returns a structure, that then contains a member `x`, building up an entire structure just to fetch one element may be inefficient.  By contrast, if this was a recognized as a hot spot and the parent container could treat a `coords[ind index].x` construct...

Comment: ...as a form of operator, it could limit its actions to those that would be necessary to compute the required value for `x`.

Comment: People. This is _sooooo_ the wrong site for this discussion.

Comment: @rtpax: For what it's worth, the way Bjarne's `operator.` works is similar to how `operator->` works; it *automatically* cascades. If your `operator->` returns a value or reference, then the system automatically calls *that* object's `operator->`. It keeps doing that until it gets an actual pointer. Bjarne's `operator.` proposal does something similar until it gets to something that returns a reference.

Comment: @NicolBolas: Except that the termination condition for `->` is really simple (did we reach a pointer type?) and for `.` the two cases are indistinguishable by mere programmers.

Answer (score 1):

There are a bunch of problems here.  The first is that now `(some_expression)...` may be either a pack expansion or a bunch of calls to `.`.  This doesn't seem worth it; even if we could fix it, it would be insanity.  You could never use `...` in any template, and as moving code into templates is something that happens, we'd have to ban repeated use of `.` everywhere to be safe.

---

We can simplify your idea and take a page from `operator->`.

> `a.b` is evaluated as-is in the current standard.  If no `b` is found and `a` has an `operator.()`, then `(a.operator.()).b` is instead evaluated.  *Note: lack of access to `b` doesn't cause `operator.()` to be used.*

Users who want "min depth" have to call `a.operator.()` possibly repeatedly.  Users who want unary have to call `a.operator.()`.  Zero magic happens when you invoke `a.operator.()` -- the method is just called.  (Note that `a.operator.()` cannot use `operator.()` to find itself, but that isn't an explicit rule but rather implicit in how `a.x` works.)

The ability to have const overloads of `operator.` is implied by the above.  There isn't unary version (doing so would make accessing binary version impossible, which seems impolite).  Only strange cases are more verbose (unary `.`, "please dot at least 2 times", etc).

Comment: after looking into variadic templates more, it seems it's a nonissue. `...` in templates either follows types (which cannot have `operator.` called)
or variadic argument, which does nat have a type or any special meaning for a `.` after it.

Comment: @rtpax `template<class...Args>void foo(Args&&...args) { (bar( (args)... )...); }` -- is that a call to `bar` with an expanded `args...` then calling .3 uses of `.` on the return value, or a pack of calls to `bar( args... )` where `...` is 3 uses of the `.` operator?  It is a mess I'd rather avoid; once another use of `...` is in the language, refactoring code into a template could become fraught.  And the benefit is ridiculously minimal; unary `.` is not something we should optimize for.

Comment: The first ... would be an expansion and (unless bar is a macro) the second would be three . calls.  It's unambiguous and extremely unlikely to occur. It does not strike me as a problem.

Comment: @rtpax; It is ambiguous, just like `{ bar( args+0 )... }` is a valid pack.

Comment: @rtpax So `bar..` is two dots, `bar...` is a pack expansion if there is one and three dots if not, `bar....` is `bar.` expanded if there is a pack, 4 dots if not, `bar......` is 6 dots if no pack and `bar...` expanded if there is a pack?  So just tricky and messy, not breaking or ambiguous.  Still, why have `..` or unary `.` *at all*?  What use case deserves short syntax and some annoying corner cases for that?